# How to use JSON on Blob Storage as parameter for Azure Data Factory?

Tags: json, sql-server, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have a stored procedure with a parameter `DateTime` on ADF, and now I need to convert my parameter as a `.JSON` file that stored at Blob Storage.

My question is, is it possible to use `JSON` file on Azure Blob Storage ? Because on Azure Data Factory I seen there were `JSON` option on `dynamic content`.

If it is possible, is there any different parameter usage on my `Stored Procedure SQL Script` ? and how to call my `JSON` file to my pipeline? Do I need to specified my `JSON` folder on blog storage?

This is what I think, from this

[image]

To this

[image]

Comment: Hi, `@json()` is a function that can convert a string in json format into a json object.

Comment: @HarrisXu So, here you are again Harrix :D , so basically `@json()` has a same function as `@string()` ? But, is it possible to load `.JSON` file from blob storage and get a parameter from it ?

Comment: These two functions can be said to be counterproductive. The former can convert strings to json, and the latter can convert json to string output. You can use [Lookup activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) to find the value in the json file, then Output the value to a variable in ADF.

Comment: @HarrisXu Woww, thank you so much !!! This is what I looking for !

Comment: Nice, do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [Lookup activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) to find the value in a json file, then output the value to a variable in ADF.

1. I sotred my json file in my Azure datalake.

```
{
    "intial_date":"2020-01-07",
    "end_date":"2020-01-07"
}
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test 
@end_date SMALLDATETIME, @initial_date SMALLDATETIME, @datediff INT 
as
begin

    print(@end_date)
    print(@initial_date)
end
```

2. Then I use a Lookup activity to fetch the value.
   [image]
3. In my stored procedure:

> end_date: `@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.end_date`
> initial_date: `@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.initial_date`

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I want ask another thing again, if I'm using `JSON` file as parameter, is there any different parameter set for my Stored Procedure SQL Script ? for now I just using this `CREATE PROCEDURE schema.table @end_date SMALLDATETIME, @initial_date SMALLDATETIME, @datediff INT`

Comment: Hi,  I may not catch your idea, I just made an example to test. I've updated my answer. I think there is no differences.